# Where to check how many jobs are currently running in YARN Cluster using Cloudera Manager?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-manager

I would like to check the number of jobs currently running on YARN Cluster using Cloudera Manager.

Is Cloudera Manager has any dashboard for number of jobs running on Cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For CDH 5.x , Under [Clusters]/[Activities]/[Yarn Applications].